# What is the Firebase Authentication import for Angular 14

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angular14

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/HEAD/docs/auth/getting-started.md#5-getting-started-with-firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use `new firebase.authGoogleAuthProvider()` and I can't import `firebase`. I've installed:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/sign-in-with-apple": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9",
    "@jest/globals": "^28.1.1",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.8.5",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^8.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple": "^0.1.2",
    "firebase": "^7.9.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

Here's a screenshot of the `node_modules/@firebase`

[image]

Here's one of the `node_modules/firebase`

[image]

Somewhere I found that I should use this `import` but as you see, this path doesn't exist. Any suggestions?

`import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firebase/compat appeared only in firebase v9, i see you are using `"firebase": "^7.9.0"` in your package json so npm will install latest version prior to v8.

To check installed firebase version - see package.json file inside node_modules/firebase directory.

To use `import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';` as per your guides - update firebase version in your package.json file and rerun npm install. Latest version is `9.9.0` so it will be `"firebase": "~9.9.0"` or `"firebase": "^9.9.0"`

More details at https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade